# How to save customized variable to a given file?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

By default, emacs saves all customized variables to .emacs file. Yet I want to save it in a separate file for easy management. Is there any way to configure this behavior in Emacs 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs-custom.el")
```